# Anaconda Navigator opening and runing

Tags: cmd.exe, anaconda

Why is my Anaconda Navigator taking so long to open, and runs so slow? It is at loading applications status permanently. How to solve it?

I have already killed processes connected with Anaconda Navigator in cmd.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to various reasons such as a wrong configuration or just bad hardware, even though no hardware should have problems running anaconda could you please give a syscall trace when you run anaconda or just what dlls anaconda is using.

Anything else as this is a very vague question

Comment: No, I think it is rather some issues connected and described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079641/there-is-an-instance-of-anaconda-navigator-already-running-error but I cannot solve it